# How can I check if custom dimensions data is working?

Tags: google-analytics

I've set my custom dimension in Google Analytics and now I'd like to know if any data is coming to GA. Do I have to wait for data to show in non-real-time reports (how long does that take?), or is there another way that I can see it immediately?

This is how I send my data:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', value);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you install the Chrome [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) extension, and enable it, you will be able to see all the details of track event logged to the console in a nicely readable fashion.

Comment: Excellent.  I love answers like this that answer a very specific problem by referencing a more powerful and generalized tool or approach.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to installing the chrome extension is to use this snippet, it's available in the official documentation.

```
window.ga_debug = {trace: true};
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) { 
 // TODO: copy the implementation here
}(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js', 'ga');
```

This basically writes the output of your ga operations (send, set, etc) to the console. So you'll be able to see if your hit was actually sent or ignored.

Comment: This answer was particularly useful for debugging Chrome extensions - which the Google Analytics Debugger mentioned above can't detect. (Since the events happen inside the extension's sandbox, perhaps)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom report in your Universal Analytics profile. Set your custom dimension as the dimension and use a metric like visits.  View report. Also, you can send along the setting of your dimension within a pageview - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets#sendingdata

Comment: No, it does take a while (1-3hrs). On the contrary, have you looked to see if the request is getting sent. E.g. [HttpFox for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) or [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna)? This way you can see if the requests are getting sent.

Comment: +1 for inspecting the actual request. If you want immediate, that's about as immediate as you can get.

Comment: I've tried, yes, but there are around a 100 requests on that page and I don't know which to check...

Comment: Of you use the Firefox plugin called HTTPFox, you can search for the utm parameter. This will give you only google analytics requests.